# WebObjects 5.4.3 deployed on Tomcat 6 resulted random StackOverflowError

Tags: tomcat, webobjects

Please advise.  I keep getting the stackoverflow error in _NSWeakMutableCollection. Thanks!

```
Caused by: java.lang.StackOverflowError 

_NSWeakMutableCollection.java 175 processQueue com.webobjects.foundation 
_NSWeakMutableArray.java 124 __removeReference com.webobjects.foundation 
_NSWeakMutableCollection.java 176 processQueue com.webobjects.foundation
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is likely a bug within WebObjects 5.4.3 itself, however I believe it is fixed in [Project WOnder](https://github.com/wocommunity/wonder)'s re-implementation of `_NSWeakMutableArray.java`; its `__removeReference(Reference)` method does not call the `processQueue()` method.

[Project WOnder](https://github.com/wocommunity/wonder) is a set of open-source WebObjects frameworks and it offers a number of important bug fixes for WebObjects, not to mention thousands of useful features with new stuff being added all the time.

Comment: Thanks very much!  What's the easiest way to resolve this without any side effect?

Comment: My guess would be to download Wonder's [binary frameworks](http://jenkins.wocommunity.org/job/Wonder/) and add these ERExtensions.framework to your project following the [instructions](http://wiki.wocommunity.org/display/documentation/Binary+Frameworks+Installation+and+Upgrade). You should also try asking on the [WebObjects developer list](https://lists.apple.com/mailman/listinfo/webobjects-dev) - it is a really friendly and helpful mailing list.